# How are the main characters related?

Tags: kamichama-karin

I watched Kamichama Karin a long time ago, and I remember that there were a lot of weird biological relations between the main characters. I know it involved cloning. I tried looking it up on Wikipeda but was kind of confused. Can someone give me a compiled/clear explanation of how the main characters are related?